# How to debug ajax response in firebug

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

My function is like this when function call at that time it's automatically refresh page I can not see that response in `firebug` this function is working properly but I can't see output in `firebug`

```
<script>
function getQty(itemId)
{
  var dataString = "itemId=" + itemId;

  $.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:"allQty.php",
    data: dataString,
    success:function(data)
    {
      $('.totalQty').html(data)
    }
  });
}
</script>
```

here call function

```
<a href="screen.php?{$a}&itemId={$itemArray[sec].itemId}" class="btn itemId" id="{$itemArray[sec].itemId}" name="itemId" onClick="getQty(this.id);">{$itemArray[sec].itemNm}</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set "Persist" ON in Network tab in Firebug or "Preserve log" in Chrome

Comment: i don not know about that how can i set that @Sargon

Comment: @Prashant - the button can be found in top left corner of the network tab in firebug. (At the right of Clear btn.)

Comment: me turn that option but in response it's shows function file it's not show me function response html..

Comment: in that i found "Uncaught ReferenceError: html is not defined" error what is it.

Comment: @Prashant - $('.totalQty').data(html): the "html" variable is not set. I think you have a typo, just change it to "data", so you will have: $('.totalQty').data(data)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82620/discussion-between-prashant-and-sargon).

Comment: me get result but it gone automatically

Comment: me update my code but i can not view that out put properly